# Why is my Flutter/Dart code adding an element to a List instead of removing it from the list

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

**Objective**

I am trying to implement a toggle action when the user clicks on a wishlist icon. If the particular item exists in the wishlist, it shlould be removed from it, otherwise it should added to it.

I have a *customers* collection in Firebase Firestore and an *instrument* collection as well. A *customers* document has a field called *wish* which is a List of instruments.

[image]

**Issue Faced**

When the user clicks on the wishlist icon for the first time, the istrument is getting added to the `customerWishlist`. However, if the user clicks on the wishlist icon of the same instrument again, instead of removing it from `customerWishlist`, it is adding the same instrument again to `customerWishlist`.

**My Code**

```
class _HomeWelcomeScreenState extends State<HomeWelcomeScreen>{

   final Stream<QuerySnapshot> instrumentsStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("instrument").snapshots();

  final List storedInstruments = [];
  List customerWishlist = [];

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   final currUser = context.read<FirebaseAuthMethods>().user;
    Future<List> generateFutureCustomerWishlist() async {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('customers')
          .doc(currUser!.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) => value.get('wish'));
    }

    void generateCustomerWishList() async {
      customerWishlist = await generateFutureCustomerWishlist();
    }

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      
      //some code for UI

      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: instrumentsStream,
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                print("Someting went wrong");
                              }
                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return const Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                );
                              }

                              storedInstruments.clear();
                              snapshot.data!.docs
                                  .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                Map a =
                                    document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                storedInstruments.add(a);
                              }).toList();

                              return Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: storedInstruments.length,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      //shrinkWrap: true,
                                      physics:
                                          const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                          int index) {
                                        return InstrumentCard(
                                          width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                                          height: screenWidth * 0.4 / 0.75,
                                          instrumentImageUrl:
                                              storedInstruments[index]
                                                  ["img-url"],
                                          instrumentName:
                                              storedInstruments[index]
                                                  ["name"],
                                          instrumentMrp:
                                              "₹${storedInstruments[index]["mrp"].toString()}",
                                          instrumentPrice:
                                              "₹${storedInstruments[index]["price"].toString()}",
                                          paddingRight:
                                              screenHeight * 0.015,
                                          innerHorizontalSymmetricPadding:
                                              screenWidth * 0.025,
                                          innerVerticalSymmetricPadding:
                                              screenHeight * 0.00,
                                          instrumentDiscount:
                                              "${(((1 - (storedInstruments[index]["price"] / storedInstruments[index]["mrp"])) * 100).round()).toString()}% off",
                                          onTap: () {
                                            Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        InstrumentDetail(
                                                            instrument:
                                                                storedInstruments[
                                                                    index])));
                                          },
                                          onWishTap: () async {
                                            generateCustomerWishList();
                                            if (customerWishlist.contains(
                                                storedInstruments[index])) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                customerWishlist.remove(
                                                    storedInstruments[
                                                        index]);
                                                print(customerWishlist);
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                    .collection('customers')
                                                    .doc(currUser!.uid)
                                                    .update({
                                                  "wish": customerWishlist
                                                });
                                              });
                                            } else {
                                              setState(() {
                                                customerWishlist.add(
                                                    storedInstruments[
                                                        index]);
                                                print(customerWishlist);
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                    .collection('customers')
                                                    .doc(currUser!.uid)
                                                    .update({
                                                  "wish": customerWishlist
                                                });
                                              });
                                            }

                                            // if (wishList.contains(
                                            //     storedInstruments[index])) {
                                            //   setState(() {
                                            //     wishList.remove(
                                            //         storedInstruments[
                                            //             index]);
                                            //   });
                                            // } else {
                                            //   setState(() {
                                            //     wishList.add(
                                            //         storedInstruments[
                                            //             index]);
                                            //   });
                                            // }
                                          },
                                          onCartTap: () {
                                            if (cartList.contains(
                                                instruments[index])) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                cartList.remove(
                                                    instruments[index]);
                                                cartMap.remove(
                                                    instruments[index]);
                                              });
                                            } else {
                                              setState(() {
                                                cartList.add(
                                                    instruments[index]);
                                                cartMap.addAll({
                                                  instruments[index]: 1
                                                });
                                              });
                                            }
                                          },
                                          isWishlisted: (wishList.contains(
                                                  instruments[index]))
                                              ? true
                                              : false,
                                          isCarted: (cartList.contains(
                                                  instruments[index]))
                                              ? true
                                              : false,
                                          instrument: instruments[index],
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),

),
),
),

}
}
```

**Request**

This is my first time of trying my hand at Firebase Firestore. I would like to know what is wrong with my code that is adding an instrument to the list instead of removing it, and how to solve this issue.

EDIT:

`customerWishlist.contains(storedInstruments[index])`

is evaluating to false even after the first wishlist icon tap. I fail to understand why. :(

Comment: At first look, I guess you should find "storedInstruments" by its ID rather its [index]. Retactor to "customerWishlistwhere((item) => item.id == storedInstruments[index].ID);" <- pseudocode.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues thanks chief, I ran a for loop to check for the storedInstruments by id and then ran another loop to remove the particular instrument from the `customerWishlist` and it works now. Much appreciated. BTW, do you know why it's necessary to check based on istrument id? I assumed that since the instrument documents were generated with an id, in the ListView.builder, `storedInstruments[index]` would by default be unique as well.

Comment: Glad you solved it! I rarely use "contains" method because I once run into a similar problem and then I`ve realized tha my Constructor was changind some NULL´s to empty strings. Since I do not see all your code, I may assume that something equal is happening to you. BTW: why dont you use "customerWishlist.removeWhere"?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues I'm very new to Flutter/Dart. Not conversant with a lot of syntax, hence making do with regular loops. Will try out .removeWhere :)

Comment: You will catch up :)...closed question?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues yes sir, do you want to post your solution as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: You can upvote comments has you like and the solution should be post by the code that you made to achieve the solution. I just sugested some modifications comparing both IDs and using removeWhere. Cheers my fellow coder!